# envelope of rays that propagate into the ellipse for $F=u_x^2 + u_y^2 - 1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have the equation $F=u_x^2 + u_y^2 - 1$ and that $u=0$ on the boundary of the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2} +\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$

At $u=0$ the ellipse can be parametrised as $x=a\cos(s), y=b\sin(s)$

Charpits eqs give me:

$dx/dt= 2p$

$dy/dt = 2q$

$dp/dt = dq/dt = 0$

$du/dt = 2p^2 + 2q^2$

where $p = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and $q = \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$

solving charpits eqs I get:

$p = p_0(s)$

$q = q_0(s)$

$x = 2p_0(s)t + a\cos(s)$

$y = 2q_0(s)t + b\sin(s)$

Since $F(p,q) = p^2 + q^2 - 1$, this implies that $p_0^2 + q_0^2 = 1$

To find the envelope i need to find when the jacobian =0 which is when $2bp_0\cos(s)+ 2aq_0\sin(s) = 0$

I am confused as to how to draw the envelope of rays that propagate into the ellipse and also how to determine the ridge of discontinuity

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have missed a sign in $\dot x_0(s)=-a\sin(s)$. Then the equation for $p_0,q_0$ reads as
$$
0=\dot z_0(s)=p_0(s)\dot x_0(s)+q_0(s)\dot y_0(s)=-ap_0\sin(s)+bq_0\cos(s).
$$
This tells us that the unit vector $(p_0,q_0)$ has to be orthogonal to $(-a\sin(s), b\cos(s))$, thus $$(p_0,q_0)=\pm\frac{(b\cos(s),a\sin(s))}{\sqrt{b^2\cos^2(s)+a^2\sin^2(s)}}.$$
As this should point inwards, chose the negative sign.

To find the characteristic that some point $(x,y)$ lies on, one has to solve
$$
\left.\begin{aligned}
x&=x_0+2p_0t=a\cos(s) - r b \cos(s)\\
y&=y_0+2q_0t=b\sin(s) - r a \sin(s)
\end{aligned}\right\}
\implies \frac{x^2}{(a-rb)^2}+\frac{y^2}{(b-ar)^2}=1
$$
where $r$ is some positive multiple of $t$.
The last is equivalent to a 4th degree polynomial equation, by the intermediate value theorem there is at least one solution between $r=0$ and $\min(\frac ba,\frac ab)$, there is another solution for $r>\max(\frac ba,\frac ab)$, but that might be inadmissible.

---

Two close-by rays associated to the angles $s$ and $s+ds$ intersect at
$$
\left.\begin{aligned}
(a - r b) \cos(s) = (a - (r+dr) b) \cos(s+ds)\\
(b - r a) \sin(s) = (b - (r+dr) a) \sin(s+ds)
\end{aligned}\right\}
\implies
\left\{\begin{aligned}
0=-b\,dr\,\cos(s)-(a-br)\sin(s)ds\\
0=-a\,dr\,\sin(s)+(b-ar)\cos(s)ds
\end{aligned}\right.
$$
so that necessarily $$a(a-br)\sin^2(s)+b(b-ar)\cos^2(s)=0\implies r = \frac{a^2\sin^2s+b^2\cos^2s}{ab}$$

Plotting that curve against the ellipse gives the picture
[image]

Comment: I thought to find the envelope we need to find where the jacobian = 0 so we can find an expression for t?

I realise my expression for the jacobian was wrong but the method of solving for t then putting $p_0,q_0,t$ back into the characteristics to find the envelope is still correct , is it not?

Comment: You use $dz=p\,dx+q\,dy$ along the initial condition curve together with all other previously computed relations to determine $(p_0,q_0)$. The zeros of the determinant of the Jacobian of $$(s,t)\mapsto(\,x_0(s)+2tp_0(s),\, y_0(s)+2tq_0(s)\,)=(\,(a+2tf(s)\,b)\cos(s),\,(b+2tf(s)\,a)\sin(s)\,)$$ tell you where to find the envelope. This is the same as me computing the intersection of neighboring rays with $r=2tf(s)$. The points at $s=k\frac\pi2$ that are inside the ellipse are the borders of the ridge.

Comment: I see computing the $\frac{\partial}{\partial s} acos(s) + 2tbcos(s)f(s)$ is quite a messy derivative because of the f(s) term so i guess your way is better?

also how did you find the intersection between the 2 rays? what did you do remove the cos(ds) terms

Comment: It does not need to be messy if you leave the derivative at $f'(s)$. But yes, by the chain rule you get $$\frac{∂(x,y)}{∂(s,t)}=\frac{∂(x,y)}{∂(s,r)}\frac{∂(s,r)}{∂(s,t)}\text{ with }\frac{∂(s,r)}{∂(s,t)}=\pmatrix{1&0\\2tf'(s)&2f(s)},$$ so that the zeros of the determinants give the same points.